# Creating XML from Datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, linq, datatable

I hava datatable with the following entries:

```
**Companyid   Deptid    Location    Employeeid Employeename    Employeeage**       
001           D001      CA           0001      Jason Bourne     57
001           D001      CA           0002      Will Smith       45
001           D001      NV           0003      Kurt Rusell      47
002           D002      CA           0008      Panda            57
002           D002      CA           0009      Fox              45
002           D002      NV           0010      Wolf             35
```

I want XML to be created in C# using Linq. Combination of comnpanyid,deptid and location are to be treated unique. Any one of those change I want a new company elemnt created and all employee under that company element. The XML should look like

```
<companies>
<company companyid="001" DeptID="D001" Location="CA">
  <Employee id="0001" Employeename="Jason Bourne" Employeeage=57/>
  <Employee id="0002" Employeename="Will Smith"   Employeeage=45/>
</company>
<company companyid="001" DeptID="D001" Location="NV">
  <Employee id="0003" Employeename="Kurt Rusell" Employeeage=47/>
 </company>
<company companyid="002" DeptID="D002" Location="CA">
  <Employee id="0008" Employeename="Panda" Employeeage=57/>
  <Employee id="0009" Employeename="Fox"   Employeeage=45/>
</company>
<company companyid="002" DeptID="D002" Location="NV">
<Employee id="0010" Employeename="Wolf"  Employeeage=35/>
</company>
</companies>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Also the datatable is sorted on companyid,deptid,location

Comment: Have you tried anything? If so, please post the relevant parts of your code and explain what you're having a problem with. If not, please try to write the code yourself, and come back if you have a specific question to ask. This is known as a "gimme the codez" question and is not appropriate for SO.

Comment: I thought this forum is a great way to understand new things. By posting my question I wasnt expecting a complete solution to my problem but instead a help, a guideline, a good resource, a good tutorial..

Answer (score 0):

```
var query =
    from row in table.AsEnumerable()
    group row by new
    {
        CompanyId = row.Field<string>("CompanyId"),
        DeptId = row.Field<string>("DeptId"),
        Location = row.Field<string>("Location")
    }
    into g
    select new XElement("company",
            new XAttribute("CompanyId", g.Key.CompanyId),
            new XAttribute("DeptId", g.Key.DeptId),
            new XAttribute("Location", g.Key.Location),
            from row in g
            select new XElement(
                "employee",
                new XAttribute("id", row.Field<string>("id")),
                new XAttribute("EmployeeName", row.Field<string>("EmployeeName")),
                new XAttribute("EmployeeAge", row.Field<string>("EmployeeAge"))));

var document = new XDocument(new XElement("companies", query));
```

Comment: A little explanation would be good.

Comment: thank you all. The data which is processed are of type datetime, numeric. In the Linq query I have put the appropriate cast but still failing wtih "unable to cast" excpetion. This is what I am doing. In the group clause I have a date so this is what I am doing Date= DateTime.Parse(row.Field<string>("somedate")). Any odeas where am I going wrong?

Comment: @rsj, if the data in the DataTable is of type DateTime, you don't need to parse; you just need to use `Field<DateTime>` instead of `Field<string>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var xml = new XElement("companies",
             from e in db.Employees // use your DbSet name here
             group e by new { e.Companyid, e.Deptid, e.Location } into g
             select new XElement("company",
                 new XAttribute("companyid", g.Key.Companyid),
                 new XAttribute("DeptID", g.Key.Deptid),
                 new XAttribute("Location", g.Key.Location),
                 from x in g
                 select new XElement("Employee",
                           new XAttribute("id", x.Employeeid),
                           new XAttribute("Employeename", x.Employeename),
                           new XAttribute("Employeeage", x.Employeeage))
             ));
```

Main idea is simple - when you building xml with Linq, you can provide any object as content of element. So, I create `companies` root element and provide query which will return content for this element. Query groups entities by three fields, and creates `company` element for each group (group key used for attributes of `company` element). And last part - from each group I select `Employee` elements and add them to content of `company` node.

Comment: A little explanation would be good.

Comment: Awesome lazyberezovsky. That was really helpful.

Comment: thank you all. The data which is processed are of type datetime, numeric. In the Linq query I have put the appropriate cast but still failing wtih "unable to cast" excpetion. This is what I am doing. In the group clause I have a date so this is what I am doing Date= DateTime.Parse(row.Field<string>("somedate")). Any odeas where am I going wrong?

Comment: @rsj you can just call `Date = row.Field<DateTime>("columnName")` it supports casting to `DateTime`

Comment: @lazyberezovsky I have tried everything but I get cast type error. Although, it worked for datetime. The errors which I get is for integer and number types.

Comment: Wow! such a silly mistake. There were about 70 attributes for a node causing debuggin so difficult. I was focussing on one integer type data value for error but it turned out to be some other for which I had incorrectly entered the casting. Now everything works fine.

Comment: @rsj glad to hear that :) Sorry, was afk, couldn't help you